# Admob doesn't load when using custom user agent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, admob

I have changed the user agent in iOS my application because I want to load a desktop version of a website in my UIWebView, I'm also showing an Admob banner in my app in the same view, the admob banner will never load as long as I'm setting the custom user agent, When I move back to the default user agent it loads normally.

What can I do to get a custom user agent for my webview and also load the admob normally?

Note: I have tried to change the user agent for all the app and also for the webview alone, yet, both ways didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Thx

Answer (score 0):

use only android user agent.
working 100%
don't use a windows user agent

demo and Working:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; HT50 Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119 Mobile Safari/537.36 ACHEETAHI/1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G7105 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 ACHEETAHI/1
```